# C# WinForms hide encryption key

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, encryption

I have a WinForms application which reads data from a sensitive file and performs calculations using that data. In order to keep the sensitive information from people's PCs, we decided to move the calculations to a web service, where the file will hide in a protected folder and only is accessible by the web service program itself.

Due to some complications it looks like it may not be possible to secure the server space in the required timeframe, so what we are now looking to do is use encryption to protect the file so that it can be safely distributed to people's PCs.

My question is this. Is is possible to encrypt a file (once, so a pre-encrypted file will be attached to the project) and then decrypt the file for use by the application without revealing

- The sensitive information inside the file
- The Encryption key used to decrypt the file

I know it is possible to generate source code from a .exe file so I would be looking for a solution that bears this in mind. I am new to this kind of app development so please excuse me if this is a stupid question and that what I am trying to do is not actually possible.

Cheers

Comment: No, it is not possible, you can only make it hard to do those two things. You can not make it impossible. All you can do is just make it hard enough it is not worth the effort to try, and that takes money to do (via specialized obfuscation software and paying experts in the field to look at your code and make it more secure)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain as far as I'm concerned this is a perfectly good and correct answer.

Comment: One way to do this would be to encrypt the data file with PGP.  However, this would be cumbersome because each user would require their own PGP key and encrypted file.

For example:  The user sends you their public key.  You encrypt the data and send it to them.  They then use their private key and passphrase to decrypt the file (in the application, not to be saved to the disk) and the application uses the decrypted data for the session.

To make this more secure, you could embed the encrypted data in the app and have the user enter their public key and passphrase at run time.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I work for a large company and am finding it difficult to locate a platform that would be happy to host this application, for various internal reasons.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you for your help on this matter - your answer is as I expected it to be. I have gone with a SharePoint hosted file which I need to grant access to on an individual basis. The file is still encrypted but no longer stored on user PCs. Still not 100% secure but better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible, you can only make it hard to do those two things. You can not make it impossible. All you can do is just make it hard enough it is not worth the effort to try, and that takes money to do (via specialized obfuscation software and paying experts in the field to look at your code and make it more secure)

Comment: Thanks - makes total sense and is the kind of answer I was expecting. Just posted to be sure.
Thanks again.